# Application of Maximizing area in a histogram algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I solved this question [Maximize the rectangular area under Histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311694/maximize-the-rectangular-area-under-histogram) today.

This left me thinking, **are there any real life application to this algorithm ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to attach a label or some text to a histogram inside the bars, one good place to put it is the center of the maximum rectangle.

And even if this particular problem isn't very interesting at first glance, there are a ton of data visualization problems that are related. And the techniques used to solve this problem can be applied elsewhere.

Comment: I am curious to see some of the related problems!