# Largest rectangular area on map/graph (other topic explanation)

Tags: matrix, area, rectangles

could someone help me with the main answer in this topic: [Largest rectangular sub matrix with the same number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770945/largest-rectangular-sub-matrix-with-the-same-number/7773870#7773870) ??
It looks like a great way to solve the problem but i have troubles to get some parts of the algorithm...

Like:

- the data structure used to store the rectangles
- the variable called left_col (in pseudo code 2nd pass)
- and where are stored the variable max_... in the pseudo code for closing rectangles.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: would you be happy with a R or Python solution?

Comment: Well, of course :) (more python)