# find all rectangular areas with certain properties in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, rectangles

given an n*m matrix with the possible values of 1, 2 and null:

```
  . . . . . 1 . .
  . 1 . . . . . 1
  . . . 2 . . . .
  . . . . 2 . . .
  1 . . . . . 1 .
  . . . . . . . .
  . . 1 . . 2 . .
  2 . . . . . . 1
```

I am looking for all blocks B (containing all values between (x0,y0) and (x1,y1)) that:

- contain at least one '1'
- contain no '2'
- are not a subset of a another block with the above properties

Example:

[image: blocks]

The red, green and blue area all contain an '1', no '2', and are not part of a larger area. 
There are of course more than 3 such blocks in this picture. I want to find all these blocks.

what would be a fast way to find all these areas?

I have a working brute-force solution, iterating over all possible rectangles, checking if they fulfill the first two criteria; then iterating over all found rectangles, removing all rectangles that are contained in another rectangle; and I can speed that up by first removing consecutive identical rows and columns. But I am fairly certain that there is a much faster way.

Comment: All edges of these blocks will be at the edge of the graph or adjacent to a "2".  Perhaps you can do something with that.

Comment: If you didn't get good answer here, you could also ask it in http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works almost in linear time (there is a small factor depending on the number of found areas). I think this is the fastest possible solution.

Inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353193/145999 (pictures also taken from there)

First, I go trought the matrix by column, creating a new matrix M1 measuring the number of steps to the last '1' and a matrix M2 measuring the number of steps to the last '2'
[image: M1 & M2]

imagine a '1' or '2' in any of the grey blocks in the above picture

in the end I have M1 and M2 looking like this:

[image]

No go through M1 and M2 in reverse, by row:

[image]

I execute the following algorithm:

```
 foundAreas = new list()

 For each row y backwards:
     potentialAreas = new List()
     for each column x:
        if M2[x,y]>M2[x-1,y]:
            add to potentialAreas: 
                new Area(left=x,height=M2[x,y],hasOne=M1[x,y],hasTop=false)
        if M2[x,y]<M2[x-1,y]:
            for each area in potentialAreas:
                 if area.hasTop and area.hasOne<area.height:
                        add to foundAreas:
                             new Box(Area.left,y-area.height,x,y)
            if M2[x,y]==0: delete all potentialAreas
            else:
                 find the area in potentialAreas with height=M2[x,y] 
                 or the one with the closest bigger height: set its height to M2[x,y]
                 delete all potentialAreas with a bigger height

            for each area in potentialAreas:
                 if area.hasOne>M1[x,y]: area.hasOne=M1[x,y]
                 if M2[x,y+1]==0: area.hasTop=true
```

now foundAreas contains all rectangles with the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can get somewhere between considering every rectangle, and a properly clever solution.

For example, starting at each `1` you could create a rectangle and gradually expand its edges outwards in 4 directions. Stop when you hit a 2, record this rectangle if (a) you've had to stop in all 4 directions, and (b) you haven't seen this rectangle before.

Then backtrack: you need to be able to generate both the red rectangle and the green rectangle starting from the `1` near the top left.

This algorithm has some pretty bad worst cases, though. An input consisting of all `1`s springs to mind. So it does need to be combined with some other cleverness, or some constraints on the input.

Comment: This solution is a lot worse than the naive algorithm from the OP.

Comment: @Thomash: it's not strictly worse, for example it's considerably faster than HugoRune's for any input with no `1`s in it. So the question is, I suppose, whether it's possible to identify cases where it's good, and use it conditionally.

Comment: Of course not, there are some specific cases where your algorithm is better.

Comment: My instinct was that it could be made to work in cases where the vast proportion of the `N^2*M^2` possible rectangles have a `2` in them, or have no `1` in them. Its main quality is that it avoids considering those rectangles. And I think you can avoid growing the rectangle in the obviously-stupid way of recursing in all 4 directions, with vast numbers of duplicates because "left then right" is the same as "right then left". It may be that my instinct is wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simpler one dimension problem:

Find all the substrings of `.2.1.1...12....2..1.1..2.1..2` which contains at least one `1` and no `2` and are not substring of such string. This can be solved in linear time, you just have to check if there is a `1` between two `2`.

Now you can easily adapt this algorithm to the two dimension problem:

For `1≤i≤j≤n` sum all lines from `i` to `j` using the following law: `.+.=.`, `.+1=1`, `.+2=2`, `1+1=1`, `1+2=2`, `2+2=2` and apply the one dimension algorithm to the resulting line.

Complexity: O(n²m).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not sure, but I think this is O(n³m), since for a given i and j it is already O(nm). Still most likely faster than brute force though.

Comment: @HugoRune No, for a given i and j, it is O(m) because it is the one dimension problem. You may say it is O(nm) because you have to compute the "sum" from i to j but this is actually not the case since you can reuse the result for i, j-1.