# Algorithm to find the largest rectangular pattern

Tags: algorithm, recursion

What is an algorithm to find the largest rectangular pattern that appears more than once in a given image? Given an input img[n][n] of bits, I would like to compute the max area of the repeated pattern.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum rectangle algorithm implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663079/maximum-rectangle-algorithm-implementation)

Comment: may the rectangle be rotated?