# largest inscribed rectangle in arbitrary polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, math

I've worked with OpenCV Stitching for a while. Now I want to do the last step of stitching: crop image. This leads to find the largest inscribed axis-parallel rectangle in general polygon.

I've already googled it and found some answers ([How do I crop to largest interior bounding box in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410449/how-do-i-crop-to-largest-interior-bounding-box-in-opencv/21479072#21479072)). The quality of output image is good despite the program run slowly (it takes 15 sec to crop image quite takes only 47 sec to stitch 36 1600x1200 pictures into 1 panorama) since the used algorithm have bad time complexity (for each point in the contour, it scan all point in same row/column).

Any way to improve this? Thanks.

P/S: I also found this book:

> Finding the Largest Area Axis-Parallel Rectangle in a Polygon
>
> Karen Daniels y Victor Milenkovicz Dan Rothx Harvard University,
>
> Division of Applied Sciences,
>
> Center for Research in Computing Technology,
>
> Cambridge, MA 02138.
>
> June 1995

but I didn't have any idea to implement the theory into code :v

Comment: I'd like to point to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32682512/5008845) solution in a similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't want to implement that algorithm; it would take quite a while, and I suspect that you would be disappointed with the performance in spite of the big-O bound.

It sounds as though you're working with a raster anyway, so you could use a [linear-time algorithm for finding the largest rectangle of zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478447/find-largest-rectangle-containing-only-zeros-in-an-n%C3%97n-binary-matrix) in a binary matrix.

Comment: A possible solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32682512/5008845). Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at this [largest interior rectancle implementation](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/lir). It uses the algorithm described in [this paper](https://journals.ut.ac.ir/article_71280_2a21de484e568a9e396458a5930ca06a.pdf). An example Image is

[image]

At the moment I'm implementing the cropping functionality into the [stitching package](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching)