# Is there any function for cropping the binary image in opencv or other packages?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask

I'm just working on images and I found difficult on cropping the binary images automatically. I'm new to Image processing. 
Example images are shown below,

Original image:

[image]

Needed output(manually edited by GIMP Image editor):

[image]

I needed to crop the image by finding the edges of a whit pixels(mask) in image. But its hard to find the approximate edges. Please help me to find out.

thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findContours` to find the bounding of the object, then use `minAreaRect` to draw your needed output, 1st image. Or you can just draw the bounding of the object, 2nd image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

mask = np.zeros(img.shape)

cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1 , (255,255,255), 1)

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0])
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)

box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(255,255,255),1)

cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.imshow("mask",mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: when I tried for this  [image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1laZW1GDsmtgH2CRfw7FVuv_SLg-ijN6R) it show like [output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cm_gsCz79frQapBETNvYQFm78QM-IPDZ) but needed output is like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ltEcLDnrjk8w-2JTLp2bpuZbT_ivuqpv).Could you please suggest me any ideas related to this.

Comment: `minAreaRect` returns smallest rectangle surrounding the object. If you want the boundary you can just draw the contour as image 2.

Comment: I want to wrap the object from the image by perspective transform, for that I need edge points, I already tried 'Finding extreme points in contours with OpenCV' by Adrian Rosebrock (pyimagesearch blog owner), but for my case it's not working very well. So that's why I'm posting this question.

Comment: So you want to draw a quadrangle which is closest to the object?

Comment: yes if it makes me to extract the object from the image. My target is to crop the object without noise.

Comment: So you should read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759253/how-to-crop-the-internal-area-of-a-contour

Comment: I already tried that too, almost similar [output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F79alSe2teEpiFtk-PRhI80NB0ro-5lf), I just want to pick the white pixels to form a new image not black.