# OpenCV Python Numpy : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to crop an image to the boundaries of a contour. I've found a code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28759496/8738452)

```
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 255, -1)
out = np.zeros_like(image)
out[mask == 255] = image[mask == 255]

(y, x) = np.where(mask == 255)
(topy, topx) = (np.min(y), np.min(x))
(bottomy, bottomx) = (np.max(y), np.max(x))
out = out[topy: bottomy + 1, topx:bottomx + 1]

crop_img = image[topy: bottomy + 1, topx:bottomx + 1]
cv2.imshow("croppedd", crop_img)
```

where `c` is a contour.

I'm getting error like :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_shapes.py", line 66, in <module>
    (y, x) = np.where(mask == 255)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How can I solve my issue?

- Python version 3.7
- OpenCV version 3.4.4

I don't think this is related to my image but, here my image;

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you are referring to above is loading image in `grayscale` mode using

```
image = cv2.imread('...', 0)
```

Here, `0` refers to `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` flag. This is important because in this case, the `image` will have just `1` channel. If you load your image in this way and run your code, it will work fine. I already tested it. In this case, `(y, x) = np.where(mask == 255)` won't give any error as output of `np.where(mask == 255)` is a tuple of two numpy array, since `mask` is a `2d` array(check it using `mask.shape`).

But, if you are loading your image as `image = cv2.imread('...')` and not doing something like `image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` to convert it to grayscale, then in this case, `np.where(mask == 255)` return a tuple of three numpy array as `mask` is a `3d` array here This is the reason why you are getting above error.

Answer (score 2):

Look at

```
np.where(mask == 255)
```

without the `x,y` unpacking.  My guess it is a 3 element tuple.  `where` produces an array for each dimension of the input array.  If `mask` is 3d (x,y,channel), the `where` is a (3,) tuple.

Comment: `np.where(mask == 255)` is definitely returning a tuple of size above or below 2.