# How to handle image size variation in Deep Learning?

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on a image classification model which classify images into 5 categories.
I have 5000 training images data stored in a folder but all images are of **different heigth and width**.
like this -

```
'631.jpg': {'width': 81, 'heigth': 25},
'8595.jpg': {'width': 1173, 'heigth': 769},
'284.jpg': {'width': 94, 'heigth': 75},
'5999.jpg': {'width': 4220, 'heigth': 1951}
```

Can anyone tell me about any technique to handle this kind of data ?

Comment: depending on the task and the content of the images there are basicslly 3 approaches: 1. Resize all the images to a defined size. 2. Crop the most important part of the images to a defined size. 3. use a fully convolutional network architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(image, desired_height, desired_width)
```

Images smaller than `desired_height` and `desired_width` will be padded, and those larger will be centrally cropped.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_, ((first, *rest), _) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

modified = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(first[None, ...]/255, 48, 48)

plt.imshow(tf.squeeze(modified))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, i want to get object from image i know width and height of each object but i don't know if opencv can do without deep leaning or some things else, thanks for your help, you can found my old question if you can answer it and thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127788/detect-object-by-name-of-card-and-crop-it-using-opencv