# Crop image after stitching

Tags: c++, opencv, crop, opencv-stitching

After i stitched 2 images using OpenCV C++, i want to crop the image to remove the black area around the stitched image. I will lose a part of the image but it is ok. the image look like this:

[image]

How can i find the image corners and crop all the black area ??

If there any good references, please provides me with some of it.

Regards,

Comment: you could give my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410449/how-do-i-crop-to-largest-interior-bounding-box-in-opencv/21479072#21479072 a try

Comment: Thank you , the code in the link is very good, but may be needs some optimize. thanks a lot.

Comment: yes, it is definitely not optimized ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, in some cases the code didn't crop the image right. that make me lose a big part of the image.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using this piece of code from DJI dev guide (search for section "Cropping the Panorama"). https://dji-dev.gitbooks.io/mobile-sdk-tutorials/content/en/iOS/PanoDemo/PanoDemo_en.html#stitching-photos

The algorithm does not seem very robust at first glance, but so far it has proven to be good enough for my stitching use cases. However, I believe the code got a couple of bugs on these two lines

```
bool isBottomNotBlack=checkBlackRow(gray, roiRect.y+roiRect.height,roiRect);
bool isRightNotBlack=checkBlackColumn(gray, roiRect.x+roiRect.width,roiRect);
```

which should be changed to

```
bool isBottomNotBlack=checkBlackRow(gray, roiRect.y+roiRect.height-1,roiRect);
bool isRightNotBlack=checkBlackColumn(gray, roiRect.x+roiRect.width-1,roiRect);
```

Otherwise, you may get non-systematic C's bad excess error. 
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

cropping is now integrated in the [opencv_stitching_tool](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.x/apps/opencv_stitching_tool)

Comment: Any chance have a better link/direct part about cropping