# Cropping to only valid pixels after remap with fisheye (equidistant) stereo rectification?

Tags: python, opencv

I have two cameras offset horizontally and have acquired their calibration parameters (Camera Matrix and Distortion Coefficients, as well as the transform between them) using Kalibr under the pinhole-equidistant model (distortion coefficients `k1, k2, k3, k4`).

I want to use openCVs [`cv.fisheye.stereoRectify`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html#gac1af58774006689056b0f2ef1db55ecc) to create new projection matrices for each camera that i can feed into [`cv.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html#ga0d37b45f780b32f63ed19c21aa9fd333) and then into [`cv.remap`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4) to rectify and undistort each image.

Unfortunately even with the `balance` parameter in fisheye.stereoRectify set to 0 the `remap`ed images still have black pixels bowing into them. I want to crop each image such that no invalid pixels exist in either of the undistorted camera images.

I see that the standard [`cv.stereoRectify`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga617b1685d4059c6040827800e72ad2b6) function has an `alpha` parameter that does exactly this. But it seems like `cv.fisheye.stereoRectify` does not have this parameter. Thus I want to replicate its features.

`cv.stereoRectify` seems to use the radtan distortion model (distortion parameters `k1, k2, p1, p2`) so I dont think i can easily swap that function in since i dont have `p1` and `p2`.

snippet from my pipeline to follow below:

```
R1, R2, P1, P2, Q = cv2.fisheye.stereoRectify(mtx_right, dist_right, 
                                              mtx_left, dist_left, 
                                              (960,1280), R, tvec, 
                                              flags=cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY,
                                              balance= 0.0, fov_scale=1)

map1_right, map2_right = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx_right, dist_right, 
                                                             R1, P1[0:3, 0:3], 
                                                             (1280, 960), cv2.CV_16SC2)  

map1_left, map2_left = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx_left, dist_left,
                                                           R2, P2[0:3, 0:3],
                                                           (1280, 960), cv2.CV_16SC2)

undistorted_right = cv2.remap(img_rgb_right, map1_right, map2_right, 
                             interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR,
                             borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
undistorted_left = cv2.remap(img_rgb_left, map1_left, map2_left, 
                            interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR,
                            borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

Is there an easy way to get the same functionality that `alpha` produces in the traditional `cv.stereoRectify`? `balance=0` seems close but doesn't completely cut off the invalid pixels.

CURRENT OUTPUT (`balance=0.5` to zoom out a little)
[image: fisheye.stereoRectify]

GOAL IS FOR BOTH IMAGES TO ONLY SHOW WHATS IN THE GREEN BOX (same dimensions on either if that isn't clear,whichever has a smaller valid pixel rectangle):

[image: goal]

Comment: Easiest way is to use Imagemagick -trim. See https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=35579

Comment: thank you, but i'm looking for a solution that will keep them both align with respect to their resolution as well, which this may not since it only considers a single image

Comment: so what you want is choosing a single rectangle that has no black pixels in both of the images? You can compute rectangle A for the first image and rectanglw B for the second and combine them with rectangle intersection: C = A & B

Comment: Could you add the "left image distorted" and "right image distorted" images to the post without the axis with numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the pictures until Monday as 4hwy are on my work machine and am gone home for the weekend. @Micka that approach is correct (the intersection of ROI) but I don't know how to calculate the ROI for a single image

Comment: @Taako take a look at [Largest rectangle in a polygon](https://d3plus.org/blog/behind-the-scenes/2014/07/08/largest-rect/)

Comment: have a look at this one, which should work ok in many cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410449/how-do-i-crop-to-largest-interior-bounding-box-in-opencv/21479072#21479072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in Imagemagick using -trim. I note that -trim can keep track of the offsets of the upper left corner after the trim relative to where it was before the trim (by leaving off +repage, which clears that geometry information). So I trim each image and have it keep track. Then I place the trimmed images in a black background separately and then append the two results side-by-side and then trimmed the black again.

Since the originals were not provided, I cut the images out of what was provided.

Left:

[image]

Right:

[image]

```
magick left.png -format "%wx%h" -write info: -fuzz 15% -trim \
-fuzz 5% -define trim:percent-background=0 \
-define trim:background-color=black -trim left_im_trim.png

magick right.png -format "%wx%h" -write info: -fuzz 15% -trim \
-fuzz 5% -define trim:percent-background=0 \
-define trim:background-color=black -trim right_im_trim.png


magick \
\( left_im_trim.png -set page "%wx+0+%Y" -background black -flatten \)  \
\( right_im_trim.png -set page "%wx+0+%Y" -background black -flatten \) \
-background black +append \
-define trim:percent-background=0 \
-define trim:background-color=black \
-trim +repage left_right_trim_append.png
```

Left Trimmed:

[image]

Right Trimmed:

[image]

Appended and Trimmed Again:

[image]

I left the 3 commands above separate so that one could see the results. But they could all be combined into 1 long command line.

Comment: This looks great! The only thing is the appeneded images semester to be offset, I don't want to append the images at the end but it appears your appended images have different absolute ROI regions. For my application I'll want both images to have the same size ROI and same pixel based ROI bounding boxes

Comment: So for instance if the left images has a bounding boxes roi set by the rectangle defined by the topeft and bottom right corner as ( (xTL, yTL) , (xBR, yBR)) and the same for the right image, I want to crop both to the intersection of these ROI rectangles

Comment: There must be some way in opencv to create a mask using the output of the. Image magick trim that preserves the whitespace on the edges and then get the intersection of masks

Comment: I just had an idea, since I have the map for undistorting the image can't I apply that to each row/column defining the edges of the original image and find the pixel that's warped inwards the most fo the top/bottom/left/right of the original image to find the ROI for each?

Comment: The ROI regions of the two image will not match without some black. So if you put them together and get the corresponding ROI of both, you will see some black on one or the other. If that is what you want, I can do that. I will get back with that result and code. If you just need space between the two of my appended images, replace +append with +smush 10 for 10 pixels space between them.

Comment: OK, I have modified my code in the answer so that they are trimmed to the same smaller height in the append.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to simply set the `alpha` value to `0.0`. In the OpenCV documentation: `alpha=0` means that the rectified images are zoomed and shifted so that only valid pixels are visible (no black areas after rectification).

---

Alternatively, you can implement your own algorithm for this, something like:

Imagine that I have these two images, after rectifying (the green lines are just to visually check that the rectification is correct):

```
R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, roi1, roi2 = \
        cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1=k_1,
                          distCoeffs1=dist_coeff,
                          cameraMatrix2=k_2,
                          distCoeffs2=dist_coeff,
                          imageSize=(width, height),
                          R=r_stereo,
                          T=t_stereo,
                          flags=cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY,
                          alpha=1.0
                          )

map1x, map1y = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    cameraMatrix=k_1,
    distCoeffs=dist_coeff,
    R=R1,
    newCameraMatrix=P1,
    size=(width, height),
    m1type=cv2.CV_32FC1)

map2x, map2y = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    cameraMatrix=k_2,
    distCoeffs=dist_coeff,
    R=R2,
    newCameraMatrix=P2,
    size=(width, height),
    m1type=cv2.CV_32FC1)

im_1_rect = cv2.remap(im_1, map1x, map1y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
im_2_rect = cv2.remap(im_2, map2x, map2y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

result = np.hstack((im_1_rect, im_2_rect))
for tmp_col in range(20, height, 30):
    result = cv2.line(result, (0, tmp_col), (int(2.0 * width), tmp_col), (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow("rectified image", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

The trick is to project the points in the border of the image to the rectified image and then check the projected `u` and `v` coordinates. For example, here I will show you how we can project the corners of the original image to the rectified images (painted in red):

```
pts = np.array([[[0, 0]], [[width - 1, 0]], [[0, height - 1]], [[width - 1, height - 1]]], dtype=np.float64)
pts_transformed_l = cv2.undistortPoints(pts, k_1, dist_coeff, R=R1, P=P1)
pts_transformed_r = cv2.undistortPoints(pts, k_2, dist_coeff, R=R2, P=P2)
for pt in pts_transformed_l:
    u, v = pt[0]
    result = cv2.circle(result, (int(round(u)), int(round(v))), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
for pt in pts_transformed_r:
    u, v = pt[0]
    u += 640
    result = cv2.circle(result, (int(round(u)), int(round(v))), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
cv2.imshow("rectified image with corners", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Let's start with the cropping the height. To do that, we warp the top and bottom points to each of the rectified images. We want the largest `v` for the top part and the smallest `v` for the bottom part. Note that now we need to consider all the points of the top `(0, 0), (0, 1), ... (width-1, 0)` since the rectified images have generally curved borders. In other words, we basically want to find the largest `v` in the red points and the smallest `v` in the points in blue in this image:

[image]

```
""" crop in the v direction """
pts_top_list = []
pts_bot_list = []
for i in range(width):
    pt_tmp = [[i, 0]]
    pts_top_list.append(pt_tmp)
    pt_tmp = [[i, height]]
    pts_bot_list.append(pt_tmp)
pts_top = np.asarray(pts_top_list, dtype=np.float64)
pts_bot = np.asarray(pts_bot_list, dtype=np.float64)

# top part - larger v
v_top = 0
## rectified image 1
pts_transformed_l = cv2.undistortPoints(pts_top, k_1, dist_coeff, R=R1, P=P1)
for pt in pts_transformed_l:
    _, v = pt[0]
    if math.ceil(v) > v_top:
        v_top = math.ceil(v)
## rectified image 2
pts_transformed_r = cv2.undistortPoints(pts_top, k_2, dist_coeff, R=R2, P=P2)
for pt in pts_transformed_r:
    _, v = pt[0]
    if math.ceil(v) > v_top:
        v_top = math.ceil(v)

# bottom part - smaller v
v_bot = height
## rectified image 1
pts_transformed_l = cv2.undistortPoints(pts_bot, k_1, dist_coeff, R=R1, P=P1)
for pt in pts_transformed_l:
    _, v = pt[0]
    if int(v) < v_bot:
        v_bot = int(v)
## rectified image 2
pts_transformed_r = cv2.undistortPoints(pts_bot, k_2, dist_coeff, R=R2, P=P2)
for pt in pts_transformed_r:
    _, v = pt[0]
    if int(v) < v_bot:
        v_bot = int(v) 

result_cropped_v = result[v_top:v_bot, :]
cv2.imshow("rectified cropped v", result_cropped_v)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

You can apply the same in the `u` direction. Just be careful that if you crop in `u` and you are estimating disparity, you will need to take that into consideration before estimating depth!

```
""" crop in the u direction (for both images) """
pts_left_list = []
pts_rght_list = []
for i in range(width):
    pt_tmp = [[0, i]]
    pts_left_list.append(pt_tmp)
    pt_tmp = [[width, i]]
    pts_rght_list.append(pt_tmp)
pts_left = np.asarray(pts_left_list, dtype=np.float64)
pts_rght = np.asarray(pts_rght_list, dtype=np.float64)

# rectified image 1
## left part - larger u
u_left_1 = 0
pts_transformed_l = cv2.undistortPoints(pts_left, k_1, dist_coeff, R=R1, P=P1)
for pt in pts_transformed_l:
    u, _ = pt[0]
    if math.ceil(u) > u_left_1:
        u_left_1 = math.ceil(u)
## right part - smaller u
u_right_1 = width
pts_transformed_r = cv2.undistortPoints(pts_rght, k_1, dist_coeff, R=R1, P=P1)
for pt in pts_transformed_r:
    u, _ = pt[0]
    if int(u) < u_right_1:
        u_right_1 = int(u)

# rectified image 2
## left part - larger u
u_left_2 = 0
pts_transformed_l = cv2.undistortPoints(pts_left, k_2, dist_coeff, R=R2, P=P2)
for pt in pts_transformed_l:
    u, _ = pt[0]
    if math.ceil(u) > u_left_2:
        u_left_2 = math.ceil(u)
## right part - smaller u
u_right_2 = width
pts_transformed_r = cv2.undistortPoints(pts_rght, k_2, dist_coeff, R=R2, P=P2)
for pt in pts_transformed_r:
    u, _ = pt[0]
    if int(u) < u_right_2:
        u_right_2 = int(u)

im_1_rect_cropped = im_1_rect[v_top:v_bot, u_left_1:u_right_1]
im_2_rect_cropped = im_2_rect[v_top:v_bot, u_left_2:u_right_2]
result_cropped = np.hstack((im_1_rect_cropped, im_2_rect_cropped))
for tmp_col in range(20, height, 30):
    result = cv2.line(result_cropped, (0, tmp_col), (int(2.0 * width), tmp_col), (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv2.imshow("rectified image cropped", result_cropped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]