# Find best coordinates in PIL image for insert rectangular image

Tags: python-3.x, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, legend

I edited this post in order to ask a more clear question.

Starting from a figure plot generate by Matplotlib like this :
[image: Example]

Bitmap data is returned by a function:

```py
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def fig2rgb ( fig ):
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.canvas.draw ( )
 
    pil_fig=Image.frombytes('RGB',
                             fig.canvas.get_width_height(),
                             fig.canvas.tostring_rgb() )
    return pil_fig

figure = plt.etcetera ...
...
fig_datas=fig2rgb (figure)
```

I have **another rectangular PIL image** with definite dimension (*height=**a*** and *width=**b***) which can be inclued in PIL figure generated before.
How can we find an available rectangular zone with those finite dimensions in the whitespace of figure plot ?

The final result should be :

[image]

My initial hypothesis was to use a function that returns pixel coordinates of white space in figure and try to find x,y in them:

```py
def getWhite_coords(rgb):
    white_positions = [[x,y] for x in range(rgb.size[0]) for y in range(rgb.size[1]) \
                          if rgb.getdata()[x+y*rgb.size[0]] == (255,255,255)]
    return np.array(white_positions)

white_space=getWhite_coords(fig_datas)

for y in range(a):
    if all([x,y] in white_space for x in range(b)):
        ...
        break
```

This method has not shown results for my aim.
All this presented above is trying to simulate what legend box does when its argument `loc="best"` is setted.

Do you have any proposals?

Thanks in advance for the reply

Comment: Have a look here https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/lir

Comment: And here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70365569/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell really thank you ! Your help has been very usefull.