# The biggest rectangle inside a polygon in python

Tags: python, image-processing, vector

I want to create a function in python to mask a image using the biggest (and possible) rectangle inside a vector sample (shapefile). Could you help me?

E.g: If I have this polygon below I want to find the red rectangle. The rectangle should be aligned with the x and y axes, like in the picture.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Xcc.png)

Thak you!

obs.: I didn't even know a way to do this, so I'm not sharing the code.

Comment: By 'biggest' you presumably mean 'the largest surface area'? Your question is really a math question and not at all about Python or image-processing, and thus not really suited to StackOverflow. If you find the right math to solve this issue, and have trouble implementing the code in Python, or perhaps in a specific library, feel free to return and ask questions about the relevant code. (I'll note that it matters if your polygon is entirely convex or not - if not, you'll have a harder problem to solve; similarly, it also matters if your rectangle needs to align with specific axes)

Comment: Thank you! :) The purpose of the question is to find out if anyone has used a library or knows how to do this in Python, because making a rectangle for each vector by hand is very tiring. This type of analysis is quite common in image processing, which is why I tagged it. I'm not looking for a mathematical formulation of this, mainly because it won't add anything to my process... And yes.. in this case, I'm assuming that all my polygons are convex.

Comment: You'll note that asking for library recommendations is another clear reason to get your question closed on StackOverflow - it's not the right place for it. Also, please research a question before posting it. I had already voted to close on account of it not being about programming to begin with, but it turns out your question is also a duplicate, and likely to get closed for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362355/finding-largest-inscribed-rectangle-in-polygon