how to find the maximum area rectangle inside a contours
I have a question. How I can find the maximum area rectangle inside a contours? Now I don't have an idea.
My approach to the problem is below.
Thanks for any help.


import cv2
import numpy as np
import math


image_path = r"\\acvnas03\ACVNAS03_DATA\60.pd\03. SMT\3. Method\9. File tam\python_k-xoa_T.anh\New folder\kiem_truoc_lo\ROI\H9300600\Bside\IC3.jpg" 
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
#cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
gg = cv2.drawContours(thresh, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)  
#cv2.imshow("thres6h",gg)
   
edges = cv2.Canny(gg, 100, 200)   
#cv2.imshow("edges",edges)

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
closed_edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cv2.imshow("Origin6546 al image", closed_edges)
#cv2.imwrite("Origin6546.jpg",closed_edges)

contours2, _ = cv2.findContours(closed_edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

gg2 = cv2.drawContours(thresh, contours2, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
#cv2.imshow("gg2",gg2)
  

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Can the rectangle be rotated?

search for things like "largest interior rectangle" or "largest inscribed rectangle". See some inspirations like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362355/finding-largest-inscribed-rectangle-in-polygon/70365569#70365569 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410449/how-do-i-crop-to-largest-interior-bounding-box-in-opencv

also have a look at this: https://github.com/OpenStitching/lir

hi all. the rectangle can rotate.  I tried LIR and the result is wrong.

Hi @Micka I have try "largest interior rectangle" or "largest inscribed rectangle" but the result is not good and very slow

first, find the right algorithm, then figure out how to make it fast. if someone wrote a bunch of naive python, that can still be made fast.

@tuananh If the rectangle can rotate, first find the direction of one axis, i.e. x- or y-axis and normalize your image. In your example it looks like you can achieve this via projection, i.e. integrating pixels along tilted lines, and maximum search. Afterwards, you can use algorithms that rely on axis-parallel rectangles.

raw image would be required @tuananh

hi @André. I will try your ideal. thank you very much.

hi @TinoD. I added the raw image. Do you have any ideas?

what do you need the (oriented) maximum area rectangle for?

hi @ChristophRackwitz. sorry for reply late. I want to find the rotating component in PCB after go to thereflow.  in above picture, i want to use cv2.contours and cv2.morphologyEx to detect the IC, the result is first image. after that I want to find how many degrees is the component rotated?
if you have many ideal, let me know.
thank you for your help.
