# Obtain location of largest rectangle

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to follow the code in the answer here: [Find largest rectangle containing only zeros in an N×N binary matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478447/find-largest-rectangle-containing-only-zeros-in-an-n%C3%97n-binary-matrix)

I'm having difficulty understanding how to find the origin `(x,y)` of the largest rectangle found by the algorithm.

from collections

```
import namedtuple
from operator import mul
import numpy as np
import functools

x = np.zeros(shape=(4,5))
x[0][0] = 1
x[0][1] = 1
x[0][2] = 1
x[0][3] = 1
x[1][0] = 1
x[1][1] = 1
x[1][2] = 1
x[1][3] = 1
print(x)
print(max_size(x))

Info = namedtuple('Info', 'start height')

def find_maximum_frame(mat, value=1):
    """Find height, width of the largest rectangle containing all `value`'s."""
    it = iter(mat)
    hist = [(el==value) for el in next(it, [])]
    max_size, _ = max_rectangle_size(hist)
    old_size = (0,0)
    coordinates = None
    for y,row in enumerate(it):
        hist = [(1+h) if el == value else 0 for h, el in zip(hist, row)]
        new_rect, c = max_rectangle_size(hist)
        max_size = max(max_size, new_rect, key=area)
        if max_size[0]*max_size[1] > old_size[0]*old_size[1]:
            coordinates = [c[0], (y+2)-max_size[0]]
        old_size = max_size
    return [max_size, coordinates]

def max_rectangle_size(histogram):
    """Find height, width of the largest rectangle that fits entirely under
    the histogram.
    """
    stack = []
    top = lambda: stack[-1]
    max_size = (0, 0) # height, width of the largest rectangle
    pos = 0 # current position in the histogram
    for pos, height in enumerate(histogram):
        start = pos # position where rectangle starts
        while True:
            if not stack or height > top().height:
                stack.append(Info(start, height)) # push
                print(stack)
            elif stack and height < top().height:
                max_size = max(max_size, (top().height, (pos - top().start)),
                               key=area)
                start, _ = stack.pop()
                continue
            break # height == top().height goes here

    pos += 1
    coordinates = [0,0]
    old_size = (0,0)
    for start, height in stack:
        max_size = max(max_size, (height, (pos - start)), key=area)
        if max_size[0]*max_size[1] > old_size[0]*old_size[1]:
            coordinates = [start,height]
        old_size = max_size
    return [max_size, coordinates]

def area(size):
    return functools.reduce(mul, size)
```

The above code seems to work to in my example to find the upper left-hand corner of the rectangle, but when I try it on a larger image it's breaking down and I can't debug why.

Comment: The line `if sum(max_size) > sum(old_max):` is incorrect because sum doesn't give you area. You need to take the product. To get the x-coordinate you will have to return it from `max_rectangle_size`.

Comment: @LawrenceWu yeah I actually changed this locally but forgot to edit my question. It doesn't seem like this works properly even on a simple example. Edited my question to include the example.

Comment: I haven't run your code but it looks like it will return the bottom (the greatest y coordinate) of the rectangle. Is this not what happens?

Comment: @LawrenceWu just updated my code to be runnable

Comment: @LawrenceWu when I do a `print(stack)` after the initial while loop, I get this repeated over and over again `[Info(start=0, height=0)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a solution that modifies the [Gist version](https://gist.github.com/zed/776423) of J.F. Sebastian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4671342/1628638):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Info = namedtuple('Info', 'start height')

# returns height, width, and position of the top left corner of the largest
#  rectangle with the given value in mat
def max_size(mat, value=0):
    it = iter(mat)
    hist = [(el==value) for el in next(it, [])]
    max_size_start, start_row = max_rectangle_size(hist), 0
    for i, row in enumerate(it):
        hist = [(1+h) if el == value else 0 for h, el in zip(hist, row)]
        mss = max_rectangle_size(hist)
        if area(mss) > area(max_size_start):
            max_size_start, start_row = mss, i+2-mss[0]
    return max_size_start[:2], (start_row, max_size_start[2])

# returns height, width, and start column of the largest rectangle that
#  fits entirely under the histogram
def max_rectangle_size(histogram):
    stack = []
    top = lambda: stack[-1]
    max_size_start = (0, 0, 0) # height, width, start of the largest rectangle
    pos = 0 # current position in the histogram
    for pos, height in enumerate(histogram):
        start = pos # position where rectangle starts
        while True:
            if not stack or height > top().height:
                stack.append(Info(start, height)) # push
            elif stack and height < top().height:
                max_size_start = max(
                    max_size_start,
                    (top().height, pos - top().start, top().start),
                    key=area)
                start, _ = stack.pop()
                continue
            break # height == top().height goes here

    pos += 1
    for start, height in stack:
        max_size_start = max(max_size_start, (height, pos - start, start),
            key=area)

    return max_size_start

def area(size): return size[0]*size[1]
```

The code passes all tests from the [Gist version](https://gist.github.com/zed/776423) once the positions are added to the tests.  Here, e.g., the first test:

```
    self.assertEqual(max_size(self.__s2m("""
    0 0 0 0 1 0
    0 0 1 0 0 1
    0 0 0 0 0 0
    1 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 1
    0 0 1 0 0 0""")), ((3, 4), (2, 1)))
```

The rectangle of size (3, 4) is at position (2, 1).

Comment: yep, I ended up coming to the same exact conclusion separately. You get the bounty though :)

Comment: I used the Gist code since this seemed safer and, when done, noticed that your code was close.  :)  BTW, I took a _quick_ look to see whether `scipy.ndimage` or `OpenCV` have this, but no luck.  Using (more) native code for this problem should result in a nice speedup...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the same problem of hackerrank...

```
public static long largestRectangle(List<Integer> h) {
// Write your code here
Stack<Integer> st1 = new Stack<>();
int i = 0;
int topIndex = 0;
long area;
long finalArea=0;
while(i<h.size()){
  if(st1.isEmpty() || h.get(st1.peek()) <= h.get(i)){
    st1.push(i++);
  }else{
    topIndex = st1.peek();
    st1.pop();
    
    area = h.get(topIndex) * (st1.isEmpty() ? i : i-1-st1.peek());
    if(area > finalArea ){
      finalArea = area;
    }
  }
}
while(st1.isEmpty()==false){
  topIndex = st1.peek();
  st1.pop();
  area = h.get(topIndex) * (st1.isEmpty() ? i : i-1-st1.peek());
    if(area > finalArea ){
      finalArea = area;
    }
}
return finalArea;

}
```