# Find largest rectangle contain only 1s in the grid with python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am learning python and encounter a problem, where I need to find the largest rectangle contain only 1s in the 10x10 generated grid. I can only find the width and have no idea how to find the correspond height.

```
import random
import sys
grid=[[0]*12 for _ in range(12)]

def display_grid():
    for i in range(1,11):

        for j in range(1,11):

            print(grid[i][j], end=' ')
        print()
def populate_grid():
    for i in range(1,11):
        for j in range(1,11):
            grid[i][j]= int(random.randrange(2)==0)
random.seed(3)
populate_grid()
display_grid()    
grid
width=1
list_width=[]
for i in range(1,11):
    for j in range(1,11):
        if grid[i][j]==grid[i][j+1]==1:
            width+=1
            list_width.append(width)
        else:
            width=1
print(list_width)


1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277859/obtain-location-of-largest-rectangle).

Comment: Have you used the search function? This is one of the most often asked questions in the [algorithm] tag.