# Minimum amount of rectangles from multi-colored grid

Tags: algorithm, matrix, xna

I've been working for some time in an XNA roguelike game and I can't get my head around the following problem: developing an algorithm to divide a matrix of non-binary values into the fewest rectangles grouping these values.

Example: given the following matrix

```
  01234567
0 ---##*##
1 ---##*##
2 --------
```

The algorithm should return:

```
3x3 rectangle of '-'s starting at (0,0) 
2x2 rectangle of '#'s starting at (3, 0)
1x2 rectangle of '*'s starting at (5, 0)
2x2 rectangle of '#'s starting at (6, 0)
5x1 rectangle of '-'s starting at (3, 2)
```

Why am I doing this: I've gotten a pretty big dungeon type with a size of approximately 500x500. If I were to individually call the "Draw" method for each tile's Sprite, my FPS would be far too low. It is possible to optimize this process by grouping similar-textured tiles and applying texture repetition to them, which would dramatically decrease the amount of GPU draw calls for that. For example, if my map were the previous matrix, instead of calling draw 16 times, I'd call it only 5 times.

I've looked at some algorithms which can give you the biggest rectangle of a type inside a given **binary** matrix, but that doesn't fit my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The algorithms such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478447/find-largest-rectangle-containing-only-zeros-in-an-n%C3%97n-binary-matrix look for a particular type, such as rectangles of 0s within 1s. So if you have only a small number of different values then for each value you could map that value to 0 and all others to 1 and then find the largest rectangle of 0s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use breadth first searches to separate each area of different tile type.

Picking a partitioning within the individual shapes is an NP-hard problem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition), so you can't find an efficient solution that guarantees the minimum number of rectangles. However if you don't mind an extra rectangle or two for each shape and your shapes are relatively small, you can come up with algorithms that split the shape into a number of rectangles close to the minimum.

An off the top of my head guess for something that could potentially work would be to pick a tile with the maximum connecting tiles and start growing a rectangle from it using a recursive algorithm to maximize the size. Remove the resulting rectangle from the shape, then repeat until there are no more tiles not included in a rectangle. Again, this won't produce perfect results, there are graphs on which this will return with more than the minimum amount of rectangles, but it's an easy to implement ballpark solution. With a little more effort I'm sure you will be able to find better heuristics to use and get better results too.

Answer (score 0):

One possible building block is a routine to check, given two points, whether the rectangle formed by using those points as opposite corners is all of the same type. I think that a fast (but unreliable) means of testing this can be based on mapping each type to a large random number, and then working out the sum of the numbers within a rectangle modulo a large prime. Take one of the numbers within the rectangle. If the sum of the numbers within the rectangle is the size of the rectangle times the one number sampled, assume that the all of the numbers in the rectangle are the same.

In one dimension we can work out all of the cumulative sums a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d,... in time O(N) and then, for any two points, work out the sum for the interval between them by subtracting cumulative sums: b+c+d = a+b+c+d - a. In two dimensions, we can use cumulative sums to work out, for each point, the sum of all of the numbers from positions which have x and y co-ordinates no greater than the (x, y) coordinate of that position. For any rectangle we can work out the sum of the numbers within that rectangle by working out A-B-C+D where A,B,C,D are two-dimensional cumulative sums.

So with pre-processing O(N) we can work out a table which allows us to compute the sum of the numbers within a rectangle specified by its opposite corners in time O(1). Unless we are very unlucky, checking this sum against the size of the rectangle times a number extracted from within the rectangle will tell us whether the rectangle is all of the same type.

Based on this, repeatedly start with a random point not covered. Take a point just to its left and move that point left as long as the interval between the two points is of the same type. Then move that point up as long as the rectangle formed by the two points is of the same type. Now move the first point to the right and down as long as the rectangle formed by the two points is of the same type. Now you think you have a large rectangle covering the original point. Check it. In the unlikely event that it is not all of the same type, add that rectangle to a list of "fooled me" rectangles you can check against in future and try again. If it is all of the same type, count that as one extracted rectangle and mark all of the points in it as covered. Continue until all points are covered.

This is a greedy algorithm that makes no attempt at producing the optimal solution, but it should be reasonably fast - the most expensive part is checking that the rectangle really is all of the same type, and - assuming you pass that test - each cell checked is also a cell covered so the total cost for the whole process should be O(N) where N is the number of cells of input data.