# Find the largest chessboard surface in 2D Matrix

Tags: algorithm

I'm having a bit of difficulty by solving an exercise, hope I can get some help from you.
Given a 2D Array with N rows and M columns, and the array has only elements with the value 0 and 1.
Find the largest surface that is similar to a chessboard(where 0 are the white squares and 1 the black squares) and print the size of the surface(number of squares).

Constraints:
2<=N<=1000
2<=M<=1000

Example:
N=4, M=5

```
0 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 1
```

Output: Number of squares=5 (row 2-from column 1 to column 5)

Example:
N=3, M=4

```
0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 0 1 0
```

Output: Number of squares=6 (from row 1 to row 3- from column 2 to column 3)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: pls provide your code and explain your difficulties to solve this problem. we cannot guess, if you have a compile error, questions to an algorithm, what programming language you are using etc..

Comment: Have you implemented the most obvious solution yet? For every point in the board, try to walk right and down until the "chessboard invariant" no longer holds.

Comment: A slightly smarter approach would be to generate two N-1 x M-1 grids, where the first has 1 for a cell if the chessboard condition holds on the cell to the right of it, the second grid has 1 for a cell if the chessboard condition holds on the cell below it. At that point you look for the largest rectangle among the following: {rectangle that has 1 in both grids, largest row-section that has 1 in the "right chessboard" grid, largest column-section that has 1 in the "below chessboard" grid}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework questions should show an attempt at solving the problem (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Flip every second cell in a checkerboard pattern
2. Find the largest rectangle containing only 0s or only 1s.

See [Find largest rectangle containing only zeros in an N×N binary matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478447/find-largest-rectangle-containing-only-zeros-in-an-n%c3%97n-binary-matrix) for help on the 2nd part.

For your second example:

```
0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 0 1 0
```

flipping every 2nd cell produces:

```
0 1 1 1
0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```

And you can see the rectangle of 1s that you're looking for.

Comment: Can yoy elaborate the first step? I may have misunderstood it, because that doesn't work for me on the second example. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, I did you 2nd example

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot.