# Largest Rectangle that can be incribed in a Geometry

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scikit-learn, scipy

In am interested in obtaining the largest rectangular box(edges parallel to the image edge) That can be incribed in the white region in the image. Unlike other questions of similar kind on stack overflow, I am not interested that the 4 corners of the box should lie on the edge of the white region.

[image]

I am looking for solutions on how to do it in python.

One possible outcome is the green box in the image below.

[image]

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418912/5008845) answer. Invert the image first.

Comment: @Miki great link :)