# Clustering Data in a 3D matrix with another matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, 3d, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I Have got 2 Data cubes represented as 3D matrices. Both of them will be of same dimensions. we have to do rule based ordering. our condition is that if any sub cube of both of them ( sub cube must match exactly in location and orientation) matches atleast p% we can tell that they are similar. now given two 3D matrices containing  the data , we have to write an algorithm which prints the number of similar subcubes that are similar in the given two cubes.

I tried brute force algorithm but it turned out to be very slow on large data sets. Is there any specific algorithm I can use here or any technique??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would just guess that a modified sort algorithm would help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can adapt the first solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726632/dynamic-programming-largest-square-block). Construct another 3D matrix called `count` and fill all its edge cells corresponding to matching data with 1s. Then, starting from `count(1,1,1)`, consider the cells in lexicographic order and set the `count(i, j, k)` for `i,j,k` such that the data matches to the smallest value of any of its neighbours which have already been set. If the data doesn't match, set `count(i, j, k) = 0`.

At the end, the non-zero elements of `count` contain the matching cubes, and their value denotes the width of the cube.