# Most Efficient/Logical Way To Group Blocks In A Cube

Tags: java, python, minecraft

I read a [blog](https://mcpipy.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/minescanner-convert-minecraft-objects-into-python-scripts-for-minecraft-pi-edition/) about retrieving all blocks in a cube in minecraft and writing out a python script that could replicate it. The code is [Minescan.py](https://github.com/brooksc/mcpipy/blob/4d1a9902c1973c4c49f61ec3150fb2e5a0b53e7a/minescan.py)

However, it iterates over the x, y, z co-ordinates one by one so if you have a 10x10x10 cube then it will create 1000 statements; which is not only slow to write, but slow to execute.

The minecraft API lets you set an [individual block](https://github.com/brooksc/mcpipy/blob/4d1a9902c1973c4c49f61ec3150fb2e5a0b53e7a/mcpi/minecraft.py#L137) or a [cuboid of blocks of the same type](https://github.com/brooksc/mcpipy/blob/4d1a9902c1973c4c49f61ec3150fb2e5a0b53e7a/mcpi/minecraft.py#L141).

I'm looking to improve this program so that creates cuboids where possible instead of individual blocks. However, I am struggling conceptually to come up with the best way to do this.

e.g. If there was only 1 dimension and it looked like this (W for Wood and D for Dirt):

```
WDDDDDDDDW
```

You could loop over the x-axis using a simple for loop and write a command each time the block changed.

Pseudo-code

```
for i in range(0, x):
    blockType = getBlock(x,0,0)
    if blockType != previousBlock:
       writeBlockRange
```

Would end up with

```
setBLock(1,0,0,Wood)
setBLocks(2,0,0,9,0,0,Dirt)
setBLock(10,0,0,Wood)
```

How do I efficiently extend that simple for loop to 2 dimensions and then to 3 dimensions?

Comment: Although this solution isn't perfect, for the 2D case, take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726632/dynamic-programming-largest-square-block.